# Is kernel32.dll always loaded below 0x80000000 (x64) ?

Tags: windows, dll, portable-executable

I have checked several x64 windows versions and the answer to the question in the title seems to be affirmative, even in processes with ASLR. The same seems to be true in case of ntdll.dll. However, I cannot find any confirmation of that in the MS documentation.

Comment: I want to use a certain method to obtain the base address of kernel32.dll. That method assumes that this dll is loaded below 0x80000000. The method is similar to one presented here http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?post=461639

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but what's wrong with `GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll");`?

Comment: I want to write an PE packer such that the decompression routine does not use any functions imported by the import table (something like crinkler (http://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=18158). In particular, I cannot call GetModuleHandle since I do not know its address.

Comment: Fair enough. Why wouldn't that code snippet you link to work if above 2GB? - it seems to just scan backwards from the caller's return address when calling the entry point until the 'MZ' header is found.

Comment: Actually, I should have asked: "Is kernel32.dll always loaded below 0x100000000". The problem may occur in the line before the las one in the code snippet (the address will not fit in the 32-bit register edx).

Comment: I must admit I don't get the point of the `cwd` instruction in that snippet, but all 4GB addresses fit in any 32-bit register.

Comment: CWD sets AX=0. The point is about addresses > 4GB - I work with x64 executables.

Comment: It doesn't matter because it isn't even guaranteed that your entry point is called by BaseThreadInitThunk. (I know of at least one version of Windows that doesn't.)